# Add CoreData Model shows "Deprecated Feature: Transient Inverse" warning

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode10, core-data-migration

Using Xcode 10 (iOS project), I'm updating my CoreData model based on the current Model we have and I'm getting the following warning:

"**Deprecated Feature**"
*Transient Inverse feature requires macOS deployment target 10.4 or earlier*
(the warning is on the new Model I just created)

[image: deprecated warning message]

The project compiles and runs and is an iOS project not a macOS project. At this point i've literally just created the new model not added any new entities or attributes to it.

Any pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Check all the relationships you have.
Uncheck the option transient.

[image]

Then the message disappears.

Answer (score 1):

This warning appears when one or more relationships in your Core Data model have '**Transient**' property checked.

[image]

In my case this was the way to fix the problem:

1. Click on your warning in **Issue Navigator**
2. Xcode will guide you to your "problematic" relationship
3. Check properties of the relationship in **Data Model Inspector** (see picture above)
4. If everything seems ok with that relationship check the inverse part (entity that relationship is referring to)